# Print data with NodeJS hbs package access [object Object]

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js

Trying to print data which is stored in lists on a NodeJS server on the front end using the hbs view package. Using Express and hbs.

This is what the code looks like on the server:

```
app.get("/", function(request, response){
  response.render("index", {list: list});
});
```

And on the front end:

```
 {{{body}}}
 {{#each list}}
  <p>{{ x }}</p>
 {{/each}}
```

Data is stored like:

```
 [{ x:
     { type: 'uri',
       value: 'http://example.org/hospital/Basildon_University_Hospital' },
    name: { type: 'literal', value: 'Basildon_University_Hospital' },
    city: { type: 'literal', value: 'Basildon' },
    county: { type: 'literal', value: 'Essex' },
    email: { type: 'literal', value: 'pals@btuh.nhs.uk' },
    phone: { type: 'literal', value: '01268_524900' },
    lat: { type: 'literal', value: '51.557685852050781' },
    long: { type: 'literal', value: '0.45057165622711182' } }]
```

When trying to output the property x, all I get is `[object Object]` printed, same goes for any other property in the data. Tried using list.x but then I get nothing printed at all.

Also have other data stored like:

```
[ { Concept:
     { type: 'uri',
       value: 'http://www.openlinksw.com/schemas/virtrdf#QuadMapFormat' } } ]
```

Not even printing [object Object]

What can I do to get the values printed and access the objects and lists with hbs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget to add the below on server side

```
var Handlebars = require('hbs');

Handlebars.registerHelper('json', function(context) {
    return JSON.stringify(context);
});
```

And then

```
app.get("/", function(request, response){
  response.render("index", {list: list});
});
```

then Use this

```
 {{{body}}}
 {{#each list}}
  <p>{{ json x }}</p>
 {{/each}}
```

Working example
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/N2b5M/3955/)

Comment: That prints out - x = JSON.stringify(x, null, 2);
[object Object]

Comment: aren't you using jade?

Comment: Just express and hbs

Comment: give me some minutes,, btw you should mentioned the stack used

Comment: checkout the answer now

Comment: <script src="views/js/handlebars-latest.js"></script>
         <script type="text/javascript">
           Handlebars.registerHelper('json', function(context) {
             return JSON.stringify(context);
           });
         </script>

Comment: Still get index.hbs: Missing helper: "json"

Comment: Tried creating the helper on the server, when applying it nothing is printed

Comment: see the working example http://jsfiddle.net/N2b5M/3955/ , you are not adding handler at right place even you may see this http://jsfiddle.net/N2b5M/3959/

Comment: Thank you, will take a look

Comment: Really dont understand how to use this, still getting missing helper. The index.hbs file i'm running https://pastebin.com/2huZWrVw tried running it from the header script as well as separate js file.

Comment: Share your exact workspace, and will try to see whats wrong there

Comment: @Znowman Please add that to server side, as its is being rendered on server side